# Why do i keep getting the error, " Illegal characters in file path for the code below..?

Tags: c#, illegal-characters

> ```
> ExcelDriver xl = new ExcelDriver();
> xl.OpenWorkbook("C:\ExcelWorkbooks\MyWorkbook.xlsm");
>  Object[,] obj = (Object[,])xl.GetCellValue("A2:B4");
> ```

```
  for(int i = 1; i <= obj.GetLength(0); i++)
 {
  for(int j = 1; j <= obj.GetLength(1); j++)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(obj[i,j].ToString());
  }
```

> Error at the filepath saying illegal characters.

Answer (score 5):

Because you need to mask the back slashes in that string

```
"C:\ExcelWorkbooks\MyWorkbook.xlsm"
```

`\` is used as escaping character, so you have to escape them, too. Either escape them with another `\`:

```
"C:\\ExcelWorkbooks\\MyWorkbook.xlsm"
```

or use `@` to declare that string as verbatim:

```
@"C:\ExcelWorkbooks\MyWorkbook.xlsm"
```

Comment: @MohammedFaisal so you probably have some other invalid character in that string (for example some undisplayed unicode character). Try retyping the path.

Comment: i retried as u said..still the same error. The weird thing is there seems to be no error when I write the code, but when I build it, the error appears.